# How to retrieve data/values from UIPickerView (IOS using Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

How do i retrieve/get data/values from `UIPickerView` when the user have selected from the many choices?

```
var view1 = 0
var view2 = 0
var view3 = 0

let pickerData = [["1", "2"], ["1", "2"], ["1", "2"]]
label.text = "\(view1):\(view2):\(view3)"
```

So if the user choose 1,1,2 the label would show `"1:1:2"`.
How would what the user be inserted into the tree different views be done?

Here is the full code if that helps. [Link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0add1ee348267bc59c73)

Comment: Look at the UIPickerViewDelegate, you'll want to use the didSelectRow:inComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pickerView.selectedRowInComponent`:

```
print(pickerData[0][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)],
        pickerData[1][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)],
        pickerData[2][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2)])
```